# Slight background zoom on DOM load?

Tags: javascript, background, zooming

How to reproduce the effect on this website :

https://shop.stripe.com/

I mean waiting for the DOM to fully load before showing anything, and then having the background image zooming out for 1s. Pretty cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done using different transition and transforms together. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/eHAuh/2/

Key is to add/remove classes in `document.ready`

HTML:

```
<div id="DIV_1" class="scaled"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#DIV_1').attr('class', 'animatable');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#DIV_1').removeClass('animatable');
    }, 1000)
});
```

CSS:

```
#DIV_1 {
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 472px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 600px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(https://shop.stripe.com/assets/images/showcase/thairu-kat.jpg) no-repeat scroll 50% 50% / cover padding-box border-box;
    font: normal normal normal 16px/normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    zoom:1.1;
    background-size:cover;
}
/*#DIV_1*/
 .animatable {
    -webkit-transition:all 750ms ease-out;
    transition:all 750ms ease-out;
}
.scaled {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.02);
    transform:scale(1.02);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! Other question though: why do you specify all 4 properties of absolute positionning to 0 ? Isn't top:0 and left:0 enough ? Also, why do you need to remove class animatable after 1s ?

Comment: Those aren't required. You can remove them. Even you can also keep the animatable class. the reason for it's removal was that it might override some other css.

Comment: As far as 1s is concerned, that depends on your choice. If you want the  animation to be 2s long then you can also use 2s instead of 1s

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it easily with pure javascript:

css:

```
#blackdiv { background: black; color: white; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

html:

```
<div id="blackdiv"></div>
<div>page content</div>
```

js:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var blackdiv = document.getElementById('blackdiv');
    blackdiv.style.opacity = 1;
    doIt();
};

var doIt = function(){
    if( blackdiv.style.opacity > 0 ){
        console.log(blackdiv.style.opacity);
        blackdiv.style.opacity -= .1;
        setTimeout("doIt()", 100);
    }
}
```

**[Check jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/mS8Nr/3/)**