# Zoom-out Effect Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a full page (with nav at the top, but I don't mind the background going underneath it) zoom-out effect. **However**, I want it to execute once all assets are loaded, as it is the first thing seen when the page is loaded. So I wouldn't want it being executed early otherwise it may not even be seen or just the end of it would be caught.

I have seen several examples but I've had problems with them:

- *Animating (with jQuery) the background-size property* - this made the animation 'choppy' and I read somewhere it was probably because it was being run on the CPU rather than the GPU.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/njj43kz4/

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="front"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#front {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    background: #222 url("http://melleum.com/data/uploads/1/262040-1920x1080-wallpaper.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 110%;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#front').animate({ backgroundSize: '100%' }, 1000);
```

- *Using a `setTimeout` as shown in this previous question's answer: [Slight background zoom on DOM load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844649/slight-background-zoom-on-dom-load)* - this worked smoothly, however I cannot get it working when I change the width and height values to 100%. The image starts oversized before zooming out, but the oversized view is shown. I want the fixed 100%x100% view, and no extra scaling visible. I tried `overflow: hidden` but that isn't hiding the overflow. You can see this is happening as the scrollbars are appearing and ruining the effect.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/eHAuh/15/

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="front" class="scaled"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#front {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    background: #222 url("http://melleum.com/data/uploads/1/262040-1920x1080-wallpaper.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.animatable {
    -webkit-transition:all 750ms ease-out;
    transition:all 750ms ease-out;
}

.scaled {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#front').attr('class', 'animatable');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#front').removeClass('animatable');
    }, 1000)
});
```

Any help would be great, and I hope the layout of this question is ok. I couldn't work out how to indent paragraphs without turning them into code indents. Thanks for reading and have a nice day.

**Edit 1:** The way this will execute when loaded is because the jQuery/JavaScript is in the `$(window).load`.

**Edit 2:** There was an answer suggesting to use keyframes, however these do not support IE9 and this would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in css change

```
#front  
   position: fixed;
```

or for body add

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: This! Thank you, changing the position to fixed does work but I don't like using fixed positioning. But your suggestion of adding overflow hidden to body worked, so I made a wrapper for the div and set that to overflow. That hides the overflow of the interior div (http://jsfiddle.net/eHAuh/18/).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with css @keyframes if you want using `scale`

- I have used pseudo class for adding `background`

```js
/** after page has loaded*/
$(window).bind('load', function() {
  $('#front').addClass('active')
})
```

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#front {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#front:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #222 url("http://melleum.com/data/uploads/1/262040-1920x1080-wallpaper.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  transform: scale(2);
}
#front.active:after {
  animation: animation 5s;
  /* change the value 5s to what you want */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /* added so that it doesn't return to its original state which is scale(2)*/
}
@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="front"></div>
```

As per your requirements it looks like you require this

```js
/** after page has loaded*/
$(window).bind('load', function() {
  $('#front').animate({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  }, 5000);
})
```

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#front {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  opacity: 1;
  background: #222 url("http://melleum.com/data/uploads/1/262040-1920x1080-wallpaper.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="front"></div>
```

Comment: How can you do this so that the zooming only begins after all page elements loaded (as per the OP)?  Perhaps attach the keyframes css via a jQuery `$.load()` ?

Comment: I have added a `class` after `window` `load` @gibberish

Comment: But keyframes aren't supported in IE9 and below, surely there's a method where at least IE9 can be included?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. The second version was better but it is zooming out from a corner not from the centre. In the end I added a wrapper around the div, set the overflow to hidden and that way it hides the overflow (http://jsfiddle.net/eHAuh/18/).